# Mixing in Spring Data Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

As I am gradually trying to remove Dependencies on Spring in the domain part of my library without minimal extra effort, I now turn to Spring Data and the Repositories

Originally we annotated our domain entities to look like this:

```
@Document
public void MyEntity {
    @Id
    @Getter private final EntityIdentifier identifier;

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public MyEntity( ... ) {}
    ...
}
```

and so on.
where `@Document`, `@PersistenceConstructor` and `@Id`  originate from the Spring Project and some are for a specific database backend (MongoDB).

I would like to cut this dependency and use my own annotations, that make sense in my domain - `@Document` is definitly nothing my domain experts would understand when appearing on e.g an clas `Chair` or a `Desk`.

For de/serialization with Jackson, I can create *mixins* to add specific annotations to classes without modifying them in their origin.
***Maybe there is a similar technique for Spring or some other way to achive this*** that is more elegant than creating a wrapping class?

---

Apparently I need some clarification:

Lets suppose we try to write a clean architecture application which consists out of the following modules: `domain`, `adapters`, `application`. In the `domain` module, I have my domain logic and domain entities and everything domainy. I do not have anything springy - no dependency on spring whatsoever, not even by having a dependency that somehow depends on spring.
In the `adapters` and `application` module, I do have dependencies on spring. I might use spring-data to implement the Repository-Adapters. I will use Spring to configure and glue together the application.

Now, in my domain module I have the following classes:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@HashAndEquals(of="identifier")
@DomainEntity  // <-- This is an Annotation that has no dependency on Spring!
public class DomainEntity {
    @DomainId // <-- This is an Annotation that has no dependency on Spring!
    @Getter private final DomainEntityIdentifier identifier;

    @Getter @Setter private String someValue;
    ...
}

@HashAndEquals
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DomainEntityIdentifiers {
    @Getter private final String name;
} 

public void interface DomainEntityRepository {
     DomainEntity findById(DomainEntityIdentifier identifier);
     void save(DomainEntity domainEntity)
     void deleteById(DomainEntityIdentifier identifier);
}
```

Now the task is, to provide the implementation of that interface in the `adapters` module, using Spring Data - e.g. `spring-data-mongo` and inject this adapter to the domain in the `application` module.

Now, surly I can create an class, lets say `DomainEntityMongo` which is basically the same as the `DomainEntity` just with the spring-data-mongo-annotations, then a `public interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<EntityIdentifier, MyEntityMongo>` and implement the interface `DomainRepository` by using `MyEntityRepository` and converting there and back again between `DomainEntityMongo <=> DomainEntity`.

What I am looking for is a more magical/generical solution. E.g.

- Having jackson-style mixin-classes, which provide Spring with the necessary/missing meta-data to do the work
- Configuring Spring to use non-spring-annotations to do the work (just as it is possible with the ComponentScan for non-component-inheriting Annotations)
- Or - if the data guys have crafted another innovative solution - this innovative solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can use
@JsonDeserialize(using = yourCustomizedDeserializer.class)
have a look here
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

you can customize your persistence strategy with @Persister. You may, for example, specify your own subclass of org.hibernate.persister.EntityPersister or you might even provide a completely new implementation of the interface org.hibernate.persister.ClassPersister that implements persistence via, for example, stored procedure calls, serialization to flat files or LDAP.

is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you Fadi for your answer. I could do that with jackson's mixin mechanism, too. But JSON Serialization is not what I try to achive. I desire to store my domain entities in a Repository without the need to use Spring-Data-\*-specific annotations in the domain part. For that I hope, I might either make Spring-Data-\* to become sensitive for Non-Spring-Data-\*-Annotations or to provide the Spring-Data-Annotations in a Jackson-Like Mixin-Class.

Comment: are you looking for defining your own custom persistence strategy, so you are asking to manage entity without mapping them automatically to tables or documents ?

Comment: I added another section to the question, hoping it can clarify, what I am looking for.